# how save the result of imagesc and getframe in Matlab?

Tags: image, matlab, save-image

I'm wondering how can I save or read all the frames of the image as a image. I wrote the following code, but the result from the movie_frame(fr) is a structure while I need a image with all frames as I need it for doing block matching between different frames of the image.

Thank you very much.

I tried imwrite() which is not working, because Movie_Frames(fr) type was struct. Movie_Frames is giving me a cdata which is different with the size of the image.

```
    clc
clear
close all
load im_sim
load info
for fr =1:size(im_sim,3);
    clf;imagesc(info.x,info.y,im_sim(:,:,fr)),colormap gray, axis image,
    hold on; title(num2str(fr));
    pause(0.05);
    Movie_Frames(fr) = getframe;
end
```

Comment: Is your video in color? The cdata is the image you want so by typing **imshow(Movie_Frames(1).cdata)**, you should see your frame. If you want to parse this out, you will have to either create a 4D double or convert it to a grayscale and place it into a 3D double.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. imshow(Movie_Frames(1).cdata) is working, but I don't need to show the image, and the size of image by imshow(Movie_Frames(1).cdata) is same as im_sim which I don't want. I need to save the image that shows by imagesc. which does have different size. My question is how can I save the image with the new scale shows in imagesc. info.x and info.y are the scale I need. The size of im_sim image is 479*616, but info.x and info.y is changing it to 140*180. Then, I need to save the image which include all frames as im-sim does have 54 frames. the image is uint8.

Comment: Then use `imwrite` instead of `imshow`...

Comment: Thanks beaker for your comment. imwrite will give the same size of im_sim image. I need to save it with the scale of imagesc. I tried before imresize(), but I loss many information of that image.when I execute this line imagesc(info.x,info.y,im_sim(:,:,fr)),colormap gray, axis image,       it's showing the size I need, but I don't know how can I save this imagesc as a image with all frames. size of im_sim(479*616*54) size info.x = 1*616 size info.y = 1*479 but the size of imagesc result is 140*180 which I need to save the image with this size without losing information.

Comment: @Neda Sorry, I got confused with the variable names. [imagesc](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imagesc.html) returns an image object. That object also has a `cdata` field that you can save using `im=imagesc(...); imwrite(im.cdata);`

Comment: Thanks -beaker for your comment. I tried im = imagesc(info.x,info.y,im_sim(:,:,fr)),colormap gray, axis image,
imwrite(im.CData); 
G = [im(:).CData]; but size of G is same as im_sim and it's not 140*180.

Comment: @Neda Please add clarifications (especially code) to the question itself. Your question should be self-contained, including input, your code, the result you're getting, and your desired output. For example, we have no idea what the values in `info` are. Also, if you don't add the @ in front of my name, it doesn't notify me that you have responded. If I hadn't chosen to check back, I'd never have known you commented.